# tinyMCE mceAddControl

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am using this gem.
I create 2-3 sets in config/tinymce.yml, In my page I use more than 2 instances of tinymce with configurations specified in config file.
Also this instances in a list (`ul`) I am trying to add sortable on this list. As I drag-drop one instance tinymce get disable also its contents are losses, After googling I remove tinymce before drag and apply after drop as

```
tinyMCE.execCommand "mceRemoveControl", true, "tinymceID"
```

and

```
tinyMCE.execCommand "mceAddControl", true, "tinymceID"
```

Now my problem is that after this tinyMCE does not uses the settings in my config files at all.

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify which instance of the editor you want to disable/enable for it to load the right settings. If you have an element ID for the editors, try this:

```
tinymce.editors[$("#id")].execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, $("#id"));
tinymce.editors[$("#id")].execCommand('mceAddControl', false, $("#id"));
```

or this, if you have some hover-classname to select it with:

```
tinymce.editors[$(".editHover").attr('id')].execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, $(".editHover"));
tinymce.editors[$(".editHover").attr('id')].execCommand('mceAddControl', false, $(".editHover"));
```